# Can't print counted number on the html

Tags: angularjs, counting

I am adding drivers one by one on the other page and saving them into the firebase. The aim of this page is just listing them and count how many of them.

I can count the numbers of drivers in the console, but I can't print the number into the HTML

I can't create a global variable for this controller. The variable is just working in the function

HTML Part

```
<div> Total numbers of drivers: {{driverNumber}}</div>
```

JS Part

```
var ul = document.getElementById('ul');
db.collection('drivers').onSnapshot(snap => {
    //console.log(snap.docs);
    var drivers = snap.docs;
    if (drivers.length) {
        let html = ''
        drivers.forEach(belge => {
            //console.log(drivers);
            var data = belge.data();
            var li = `<li class="list-group-item">${data.ad}<br>${data.photoURL}</li>`;
            html += li;
        })
        ul.innerHTML = html;
    }
    var driverNumber = drivers.length;
    console.log(driverNumber);
})
```

There is no error on the console.

Comment: When you mix DOM manipulation with AngularJS like this, you are asking for problems. Use the [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive to add `<li>` elements to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try change it into a scope variable,

`$scope.driverNumber = drivers.length;`

Comment: When I try this I get the same error above "ReferenceError: driverNumber is not defined". How can I solve?

Comment: you have injected $scope to controller?

`controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  // ...
}])`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.driverNumber = drivers.length;
```

Where driverNumber is global to your component

Comment: Thanks, but this time I get the error "ReferenceError: drivers is not defined" How can I resolve the error?